# Где находится указатель контекста переменных thread local?

Tags: linux, c, pthread

В коде имеются несколько переменных типа `static __thread`.
Если ядро переключает контекст потока, то проблем не наблюдается.
Если самостоятельно переключить контекст потока 1, на поток 2, то поток 2 будет видеть локальные переменные потока 1, что меня совсем не устраивает.

К сожалению, я не обнаружил стандартных средств быстро переключаться между потоками, а механизмы сопрограмм ничего не знают про переменные `__thread`.

Отсюда вопрос, можно ли и как переключать контекст переменных типа `__thread`?

PS: Если что-то не понятно, спрашивайте, уточню. Вопросы типа: зачем/почему - игнорируются, кому кто не нравится - отвечать не заставляю.

Comment: А как Вы контекст потока переключаете (и что именно вкладываете в эти слова)? И о какой реализации pthreads идет речь?

Comment: 1. [swapcontext](http://www.opennet.ru/man.shtml?topic=swapcontext) 2. Стандартная `gcc .... -pthread -lpthread`

Comment: К своему стыду впервые об этих функциях узнал сейчас от Вас. Очень интересно. А Вы хотите механизм сопрограмм так реализовать или своих легковесных потоков?

Comment: @avp Костыль хотел прикрутить к чужому коду, сделав из него сопрограмму и использовать/модифицировать функциональность не переписывая чужой код.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вот тут, кажется, все подробно расписано: https://www.akkadia.org/drepper/tls.pdf

Вкратце: на архитектуре x86-64 переменные TLS хранятся в сегменте FS. При этом там есть определенная структура данных, которая позволяет, в том числе, получить адреса этих же переменных в сегменте DS (чтобы можно было получить на них указатель). Заголовок этой структуры хранится по адресу FS:0.

Дальше разбирайтесь сами :)

PS а в Windows для x64 эта структура находится по адресу GS:0